# Restrict stylelint to only css and scss files

Tags: css, stylelint

I'm trying to configure [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint) to *only* lint my CSS and/or SCSS files. I'm extending [stylelint-config-recommended](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended) but by default it seems to be processing loads of other files as well as the .css and .scss ones I want to lint.

Examples of files I don't want to include:

- .js
- .cshtml

Exmples output from the CLI

```
debug.log
 1:67  ×  Unknown word   CssSyntaxError

local.log
 21:21  ×  Missed semicolon   CssSyntaxError

package-lock.json
 3:21  ×  Missed semicolon   CssSyntaxError

package.json
 3:21  ×  Missed semicolon   CssSyntaxError

personal.json
 3:40  ×  Missed semicolon   CssSyntaxError

Program.cs
 1:1  ×  Unknown word   CssSyntaxError

README.md
 11:51  ×  Unclosed bracket   CssSyntaxError

reviewers.csproj
 1:1  ×  Unknown word   CssSyntaxError

reviewers.csproj.user
 1:1  ×  Unknown word   CssSyntaxError

reviewers.sln
 14:4  ×  Unknown word   CssSyntaxError
```

.stylelintrc

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended"
}
```

.stylelintignore

```
node_modules
bin
obj
*.js
*.map
```

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you can use a "exclusion" glob like this:

.stylelintignore

```
node_modules
bin
obj
*.*
!*.css
!*.scss
```

Comment: Curious. `!*.scss` only works for me if I also include the `*.*` line. Do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: 'fraid not @mikkelrd

Comment: I have similar problem - when passing wrong file to styllint it gives error even file is in **.stylelintignore**

 `node ./node_modules/.bin/stylelint dont-check-this-file.yml`


This is error I got when specify linter ignored file:

`Error: No files matching the pattern "/home/user/some-path/dont-check-this-file.yml" were found.
    at globby.then.filePaths (/home/user/some-path/node_modules/stylelint/lib/standalone.js:206:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`